# How to add table in Azure DevOps discussion section?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, markdown, wiki, azure-boards

I am trying to add a table in the Azure DevOps discussion section.

I am using the markdown example given by MS from the Azure Boards documentation:
[learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#tables)

```
| Apple | Banana | Cherry |  
|-----------|:-----------:|-----------:|  
| China | US | Mexico |  
| India | EU | Russia |
```

Expected result: Table gets formatted correctly in the comment
Actual result: Markdown does not get rendered as table

No error messages appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in the Azure DevOps discussion section.

The link you provided states:

> You can format tables in pull requests, wiki, and Markdown files such as README files and Markdown widgets.